# what is the difference between one length of char*/char[] and char in C?

Tags: c, string, pointers, char

```
char str[] = "a";
char ch = 'a';
```

speaking of the difference between the two, we all know`str` point to a memory space which stored [a, \0], but I want to ask whether there is a difference between `str[0]` and `ch`?

Comment: `str` is an array, `ch` is not. That's the only difference.

Comment: Just read the string chapter of your C programming book...

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili but OP asked `str[0]`.

Comment: `str` doesn't "point to a memory space" because `str` isn't a pointer. See: [Is an array name a pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-an-array-name-a-pointer)

Comment: I'll do you one better: not only is `ch == str[0]`, in fact `ch == *str` and `ch == 0[str]`... `str[0]` is just accessing the value stored in the array `str` at offset/index 0. That makes the value of type `char`, and the value `'a'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *but I want to ask whether there is a difference between `str[0]` and `ch`?*

No.

`str[0]` and `ch`, both are of type `char`, and hold the value `'a'`. From this aspect (type and value), there is no difference.